# vscode tooltips doesn't work when using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have a weird scenario where the tooltip information when hovering over a variable in Visual Studio code stops working with the Jest testing framework. The exact same test in Mocha will show the tooltip when I debug.

VSCode version 1.16.1

This is the tooltip that normally appears:
[image: The tooltip that normally appears]

The test that causes the tooltip to stop displaying:

```
var axios = require('axios')

describe('asdf', () =>{
    it('does stuff', async () => {

        var boo = { 'hi':'bye'}
        console.log(boo)

        // uncomment out this line and the tooltip disappears!
        //var result = axios.post('', {})
    })
})
```

[github repo for reproduction](https://github.com/matbarker/vscode-jest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a bug in VSCode, reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35612)